How to make StreamPlot skip regions which gives complex results or can not be evaluated for some reason?
Many times when using StreamPlot it is hard to guess the correct limits to give it which does not result in blank plot or even the command not evaluating at all.
This is because the function (RHS of the ode, in case of first order ode) can give complex values depending on the limits given to $x$ or $y$.
Is there a way to tell StreamPlot to skip/ignore this region of the plot and generate phase plot in the region where values can be computed? This is what Maple does.
Here is an example. This is the ode I wanted to generate its phase plot
 ode = y'[x] == Sqrt[y[x]^2 - 1]

Using StreamPlot
 StreamPlot[{1, Sqrt[y^2 - 1]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]

gives the command back. Not even blank plot.

This is same command in Maple
ode:=diff(y(x), x) = sqrt(y(x)^2 - 1);
DEtools:-DEplot(ode,y(x),x=-2..2,y=-3..3)


We see the problem is that when $-1<y<1$ the sqrt gives complex number since its argument is negative.
In Mathematica one has to adjust the limits manually like this
 StreamPlot[{1,Sqrt[y^2-1]},{x,-5,5},{y,1,3}]
 StreamPlot[{1,Sqrt[y^2-1]},{x,-5,5},{y,-3,-1}]

To get the plots, and then figure how to join them if needed.

I do not know now if using RegionFunction will help.
The question is: Is there a way to tell StreamPlot to ignore regions which can't be plotted like Maple does, i.e. without the user having to figure the correct limits to use?
V 14 on windows 10

StreamPlot[ConditionalExpression[{1, Sqrt[y^2 - 1]}, Abs[y] > 1], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]

This is maybe more to the point: StreamPlot[ConditionalExpression[{1, Sqrt[y^2 - 1]}, Sqrt[y^2 - 1] \[Element] Reals], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
